# Extra quotes after every quotes when I copy and paste to notepad from excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, concatenation

I have the following text stored in a cell in a worksheet

`<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';">`

Now when I copy and paste it to notepad from that I get the extra quote sign after every quote so it becomes like the following string

`<tr onmouseover=""this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';"" onmouseout=""this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';"">`

[image]

You can recreate this by:

Copy this text:

```
<!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
table.hovertable {
 font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 color:#333333;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #999999;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.hovertable th {
 background-color:#009fe3;
  color:#FFFFFF;
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
table.hovertable tr {
 background-color:#e8e8e8;

}
table.hovertable td {
 border-width: 1px;
 padding: 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
</style>
<!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
<table class="hovertable">
 <th colspan="4">Info Header</th>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';">
 <td>Item 1A</td><td>Item 1B</td><td>Item 1C</td>
</tr>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';">
 <td>Item 2A</td><td>Item 2B</td><td>Item 2C</td>
</tr>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';">
 <td>Item 3A</td><td>Item 3B</td><td>Item 3C</td>
</tr>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';">
 <td>Item 4A</td><td>Item 4B</td><td>Item 4C</td>
</tr>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#74eb61';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#e8e8e8';">
 <td>Item 5A</td><td>Item 5B</td><td>Item 5C</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

and paste to any cell in Excel

And then Copy the cell contents and paste on notepad and you will find extra quotes

Comment: Remove the existing quotes in the string `Stystr = Replace(Trim(wh.Range("A2").Text),"""","")`

Comment: Also in the statement `Dim Stystr, endHTb, StRTb, tbstr, tbTag, ctb As String` only **ctb** is dimensioned as a `String` type. All the others are variants. To dimension them all as `String` type, write `Dim Stystr as String, endHTb as String, StRTb as String ...`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman nope I don't think that will work since Every `""` is replaced by `""""` and `"` is replaced by `""` so can't differentiate between which needs to be replaced

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by every `""` is replaced by `""""` and `"` is replaced by `""`? Are you talking about in my formula? Or the results of your code?

Comment: can you do a debug.print on `Stystr` right after you set the variable and let me know if the extra quotes appear from the start? Because I just tested it and cannot replicate your issue (at the moment).

Comment: I have added workbook you can download it

Comment: will not and cannot download macro laden workbooks. idea is to step through code and find out where it's adding the additional `""` and then correct it at that point.

Comment: okay so in the immediate window I get the result as expected but when I copy the same result from the cell I get the extra quotes I think you should really look at that file to understand what I am saying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is 'behavior by design'. The clipboard's involvement in the process of transferring the cell value from XL to Notepad++ mean that the text string is evaluated. There are a lot of scenarios that are tested for (I do not have a complete list) but it seems that your paste operation is being interpreted as creating a comma separated or tab separated TXT export file. The quote characters are being doubled up because your system is using the quote character as the **Text Qualifier** special character in an XL-to-TXT export.

Unfortunately, you do not want this transitional behavior but many others do. If you need to bypass it, copy the text string from the formula bar or in-cell while in edit mode. This is not Excel's doing or even the Office Clipboard (OCB). It is the Windows clipboard's behavior which is trying to interpret a transfer from XL to Notepad++.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you

Comment: tbh, I find it annoying as well. Any transitional conversion *should* be able to be bypassed (e.g. right-click, Paste Values type behavior).

Comment: Your statement about copying the 'text from formula bar' is an excellent solution. Thanks